# HTML таблица с прокручиваемыми колонками

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Возможно ли сделать таблицу с частично прокручиваемыми колонками?
Например, первая и последняя колонка находятся на месте, а все центральные можно свайпить?

Нашел симпатичную библиотеку для свайпов (http://idangero.us/swiper/), но сомневаюсь, что есть возможность применить ее к таблице.

Comment: у вас написано "сделать" таблицу. Отсюда вопрос, что вам мешает сделать не таблицу?

Comment: @РоманТатаринов Используется bootgrid таблица, поэтому только таблица